# Add Checked Table Rows to Email Body

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, checkbox

I have a table where each row can be selected by checking a checkbox. **Whatever rows are selected, I am wanting those rows to be pasted to the body of an email that pops up when the "Checkout" button is pressed.**

Currently, whenever I hit the "Checkout" button, the email pops up and it will display the first row in the table, whether selected or not, but nothing more.

How can I get multiple selections displayed based on if it is checked?

Table:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Checkout</button>
</section>

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo $row['Description'] ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript that adds data to email:

```
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order")
             + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent($('.loc').data('loc')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.rp-code').data('rp-code')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.sku').data('sku')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.special-id').data('special-id')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.description').data('description')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.quantity').data('quantity')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.unit').data('unit')) + '\xa0\xa0' + encodeURIComponent($('.quantity_num').data('quantity_num'));

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is terrbile idea to send emails via JS like this, You can try:

```
function sendMail(){
  var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
  + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order")
  + "&body=";

  var body = '';

  $('table tr input[name="check"]:checked').each(function(){
    var current_tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var loc = current_tr.find('.loc').data('loc');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(loc) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var loc =current_tr.find('.rp-code').data('rp-code');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(loc) + '\xa0\xa0';

  });

  body += '"';
  link += body;
  console.log(link);
}
```

You need to iterate over every TR that contains checkbox and check if it's `:checked` . 
Then add avery data that You need into your's `body` var.

Comment: This works great! Only question I would have now is that I am using `%0D%0A` to have a line break after each row of data....however, I dont want there to be a line break before the first entry...how can I make it apply to all data rows except for the first row so theres not a blank line to begin the email?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling array elements like `rows[0][0][rp-code]` outside of PHP tags.
You could create the tables more easily by keeping all nested inside the PHP tags and by echoing each table elements.
Like so:

```
echo <tr>;
echo <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]">Some Text</td>;
echo </tr>;
```

You could also do everything inside javascript, but this depends on your preferences